# Special characters after converting from CP1252 to UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, special-characters

I have a bulk of Java-files in Eclipse that was written when my Eclipse had **CP1252** as encoding. I am in Sweden and we have special character **(Å å Ä ä Ö ö)**. Now we have changed the encoding to **UT-8**. All special characters is ruined now to strange characters instead!! Is there any other solution instead of open each file and rewrite all the special characters again?

Comment: You need a tool to mass-convert the encoding. Google for such a tool for your OS, you are bound to find some free ones.

Comment: Consider [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse is using the correct encoding when you look at the Java files? Look at `Properties > Resource`

Comment: @greg-449 Yes Eclipse is using the correct encoding.

Comment: @Pisek I've tried to change encoding there but without any luck.

Comment: You have to first set the proper encoding - `Encoding>Character set>Western European>Windows-1252`. Then just `Encoding>Convert to UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue in my project. Here are the steps that I followed:

1. I first copied the contents of the file to notepad++(copy to any editor which supports
   utf-8).
2. Eclipse uses the cp1252 encoding for files by default on Windows. After copying file contents, you need to change the encoding to utf-8. You can do this by going to Window->Preferences->Workspace. There you will find text file encoding, change it to utf-8 and apply and close. You will notice that characters like (Å å Ä ä Ö ö) have changed to some strange characters.
3. Copy the contents that you had saved in the notepad++(or your editor) to the file in eclipse and save the file. That's it!

Run your project, it should not give any warnings or errors for those characters now.